# Redirect to home when React app served by S3 is called with url containing a route

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router

I have a React app hosted as a static web site on AWS S3. I have set both ***Index document*** and ***Error document*** as `index.html` (for *Error document* see later why).

My app can be reached at `http://my-react-app.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`.

In the app I use the react router configured as this in my `App` component (the top level component)

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
   <Route path="/first-route" component={FirstComp} />
</Switch>
```

So, if a user navigates to route `first-route`, on the address bar there will be this url `http://my-react-app.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/first-route`.

At this point, if the user reloads the page, or if the user enters directly the url with the route (`http://my-react-app.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/first-route`), the browser receives an http error with 404 code (page not found) but then React starts anyways loading `FirstComp` rather than `Home` which leads to a series of undesired consequences.

As I said, this happens even if in the S3 bucket configuration the ***Error document*** has been set to `index.html`, which is the "hacky" solution suggested in several responses to the same problem.

The question is which is the correct way to jump always to the `Home` page even when routes are specified in the url passed to the browser?

Comment: If you want your Home component to be loaded despite the route, you will need to rewrite your router for example, nesting your switch. Inside the home component or extracting the parts of the code that need to be loaded no matter which route to the component that currently holds your router.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map all paths to the index.html file. Because your project is SPA.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem this way.

First I have set AWS S3 redirection rules as such

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals": "404"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyWith": ""
        }
    }
]
```

In this way, any time a 404 error is raised, the redirect policy brings to the Index document (i.e. the empty key).

Moreover, to make sure that even if this configuration is not set, I have forced to navigate to the `Home` component using an effect hook in the top level component, something like this

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    history.push("/");
}, [history]);
```